# Refreshing element styles in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, element

In my JavaScript, I dynamically append elements to a div like this:

```
$('.class-name').after('<p class="foo">Hello World!</p>')
```

In my CSS, I have something like this:

```
p .foo {
    color: green;
}
```

When I test it, the new paragraph element appears, but the text stays black. Is this a case of the document not reading the class of the "p" element? Or does the class "foo" not apply to generated elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your style:

```
p.foo {
   color: green;
}
```

Remove that blank space between "p" and "foo".

Answer (score 1):

Try without the space between the paragraph tag and the class.

```
p.foo {
    color: green;
}
```

It's the paragraph that has the class, there is no nested element with a class 'foo'.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule definition is slightly off. What you have is "elements with the class foo that are inside of a p element".

What you meant was elements that are p elements and have the class foo, which is

```
p.foo { color: green; }
```